# unexpected exception: prcieBookBasedOnMarket: System.StringException: Invalid id: id: External entry point

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

i am getting this error, in the last for loop how i can get the market of the ownerId for an opportunity. where market is a custom field in User, we are trying to compare market of the user to the pricebook name which we have created seprately.

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger prcieBookBasedOnMarket caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: prcieBookBasedOnMarket:
>   execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid
>   id: id: External entry point

```
    public class HND_OpportunityHandler extends HND_BaseHandler implements HND_IHandler{

       private PVD_OpportunityProvider opportunityProvider;
       private HND_PriceBook2Handler priceBookHandler = new HND_PriceBook2Handler();
       private HND_UserHandler userHandler = new HND_UserHandler();



       public HND_OpportunityHandler()
       {
           opportunityProvider = (PVD_OpportunityProvider) getProvider();         

       }


       public override PVD_Iprovider loadProvider(){
           return (PVD_Iprovider) new PVD_OpportunityProvider();
       }        



       public void setPriceBookBasedOnMarket(List<Opportunity> newTrigger) {

           set<string> opportunityOwner = new set<string>();
           map<id,string> priceBookNameMap = new map<id,string>();
           set<string> opportunityOwnerIdMarket = new set<string>();

           // Get the list of all OwnerId from opportunity



List<Opportunity> opportunityOwnerIdList = opportunityProvider.getOpportunityOwnerId(newTrigger);

             List<User> userMarketList = userHandler.getMarketList();

             for(User u : userMarketList) {
                 opportunityOwnerIdMarket.add(u.Market__c + ' Price Book');
             }

             List<PriceBook2> pricebook = priceBookHandler.getPriceBookNameList(opportunityOwnerIdMarket);


             for(PriceBook2 prc : pricebook) {

                 priceBookNameMap.put(prc.id,prc.name);

             } 

             for(Opportunity opty : newTrigger) {
                     System.debug('hi1inforloop');

                     string tempname; 

                     tempname = opty.owner.Market__c + ' Price Book';

                     System.debug('tempname :'+tempname);

                     string tempname1;

                     tempname1 = priceBookNameMap.get('id');

                     System.debug('tempname1 :'+tempname1);

                     if(tempname==tempname1) {
                     System.debug('hi3innestedforloop');                
                         opty.Pricebook2Id = priceBookNameMap.get('id');
                         System.debug('hi4innestedforloop');                             
                     }
             } 

      }  


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in your line `opty.Pricebook2Id = priceBookNameMap.get('id');`

`priceBookNameMap.get('id');` map will return Name(string) not Id..

Modify your code and assign Id to `opty.Pricebook2Id`

Here `Pricebook2Id` dataType is Id. So you need to assign Id

---

Looks like relationship is `opportunity owner, userid, createdby in pricebook`

Create a map and store createdbyId to `PriceBook2` record

```
map<Id, PriceBook2> mapUserIdToPriceBook2 = new map<Id, PriceBook2>();
for(PriceBook2 prc : pricebook) {
            mapUserIdToPriceBook2.put(prc.CreatedById, prc);
}
```

And below map based on ownerId get Pricebook2Id

```
for(Opportunity opty : newTrigger) {

    if(mapUserIdToPriceBook2.containkey(opty.OwnerId))
    {
        opty.Pricebook2Id = mapUserIdToPriceBook2.get(opty.OwnerId).Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before I assign the Id to opty.Pricebook2Id, i need to compare the value of the market of User and PriceBook. How can i compare? If you see I'm appending ' Price Book' to the string tempname so that I can compare it to the Market of Pricebook as market field in PriceBook is entered as India Price Book

Comment: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Pricebook2 to Id

Comment: @RAT__ is this issue resolved ?

Comment: no ratan, bt i m working on it, i'll let u know if there is any issue, mean while i m also some doubts that i'll be posting in my next question, if possible plz help me there

Comment: @RAT__ Yeah sure